# Display progress and subprogress bars in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp, progress

I have some Eclipse RCP code that allows the user to load multiple files, taking a few minutes each. I'm using a `ProgressMonitorDialog` to show progress as each file is loaded (one tick per file). Works well enough.

Now I'd like to provide more feedback to the user by *also* showing the progress for each file while it's being loaded (sub progress). Each file I load consists of a varying number of 'parts', which I don't know until I've started reading the file. The sub progress work can be ticked off as I load each part.

Ideally I'd have two progress bars; the top one shows the progress over the total number of files (and also says e.g. "Loading file 'three.txt' (3 of 15)" while the bottom progress bar shows the progress for the file currently being loaded (and also says e.g. "Loading part 6 of 10"). Maybe there is a "Details..." button to reveal the sub progress bar. Do any dialogs exist that do what I'm looking for? Am I stuck coding this myself?

### *Just a note on what I've tried:*

I was looking at calling SubMonitor.convert on my `IProgressMonitor` and that almost does what I want: I can re-split and set up the progress bar for the parts - the only problem is that this reuses the one progress bar. I just want a 2nd progress bar to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard dialog exists for your need. You are on your own.